# Azure VM and Postgresql ChainlinkNode: unable to lock ORM

Tags: postgresql, azure, chainlink

To summarize, I am trying to run a Chainlink node via Docker on an Azure VM. I also created an Azure Postgresql DB and verified the VM is able to connect via psql cli.

Steps I took to get the node running (following [this link](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/)):

1. Create Azure VM
2. Install docker
3. mkdir ~/.chainlink-rinkeby
4. Created .env file
5. Set ETH_URL via an External Provider
6. Create Postgres SQL Database following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-server-database-portal)
7. Set Remote Database_Url config using sslmode=disable
8. Start the node with:

   cd ~/.chainlink-rinkeby && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-rinkeby:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink local n

My .env file:

```
"ROOT=/chainlink LOG_LEVEL=debug ETH_CHAIN_ID=4 MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2 LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709 CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0 SECURE_COOKIES=false GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true ALLOW_ORIGINS=*"
"ETH_URL=wss://cl-rinkeby.fiews.io/v1/MY_API_KEY"
"DATABASE_URL=postgresql://MY_USER_NAME:MY_PASSWORD@MY_DATABASE_nAME.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] unable to lock ORM: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused logger/default.go:139   stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Error
```

I've also tried giving a version of 0.10.8 in the chainlink startup command but the error I get for that is:

```
 [ERROR] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=/tmp user=root database=`: dial error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to connect your Chainlink node to a remote PostgreSQL database. This database is managed by AZUR's cloud service and hosted and administered there internally. The issue with the connection is that the Chainlink node wants to establish a connection to `127.0.0.1` and is therefore convinced that the Postgres is located locally in your Chainlink docker container.
A docker container is an own environment and represent an own host, so `127.0.0.1` will loopback into the container itself. I recommend you to have a look here on the official network documentation of docker: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

With the version `0.10.8` you established a connection. The issue here is now related to the USER and the DATABASE. Please ensure that you create a database and an own USER for it and not use the admin credentials (root) like the superuser.

You can enter the postgres via the `azur cli` and type in the following lines:

`CREATE DATABASE <yourdbname>;`

`CREATE USER <youruser> WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '<yourpass>';`

In addition you can have a look at this post related to the connection to your postgres database:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67992586/15859805